# Update Shiny UI layout with Javascript output

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a shinyApp running on cloud that runs for long (lots of computation taking about 25 minutes) leading to timeout. However, If I keep interacting with the page as the app runs (e.g. navigating the navbar or moving a slider..), timeout does not happen. A possible solution is to keep the web-socket active by updating a value on the current page every 5 seconds or so. I borrowed the idea here https://community.rstudio.com/t/keep-shiny-app-running-in-shiny-server-no-greying-out/27784/4.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  "Am I losing connection?",
  tags$div(style = "position: absolute; top: -100px;",
    textOutput("clock")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$clock <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(5000)
    Sys.time()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this also fails because it appears that UI values do not update or refresh as the app runs in the background, until it completes the current task. So it appears doing this in the server.R block is not the solution.

I later tried to do it differently by including JS code that can update or refresh the UI as the app runs in the background. What I came up with is this ...

```
function time_function(){
var today1 = new Date();
var hr = today1.getHours();
var mn = today1.getMinutes();
var ss = today1.getSeconds();

if (hr.toString().length <2 ){hr = '0' + hr;} 
if (mn.toString().length <2 ){mn = '0' + mn;}
if (ss.toString().length <2 ){ss = '0' + ss;}

console.log(hr + ':' + mn + ':' + ss);

}

setInterval(time_function,5000)
```

... with the view that I could update `textOutput("time_display")`  on shiny UI every 5 seconds to keep the page active and prevent loss of connection to websocket.This is exactly where I got stuck as I cannot get `textOutput("time_display")` to update with refreshing values of the JS function `time_function()`.

I appreciate all help offered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround  that keeps the R/Shiny web page active even as intensive workloads run in server.R. I would like to share my working solution.

The first step is to create a ***div*** tag or object inside shiny's UI, fluidPage() section. I have a assigned "time_stamp" id to it.

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  
titlePanel(" Testing 5 sec display of clock"),

HTML('<div id="time_stamp"></div>'), // comment: new object created. We write to it using js code.

br(),

tags$script(src = "time_print.js")
)
//server.R

server = function(input,output,session){

// do some complex tasks..

}
```

The ***tags$script*** bit is where the .js file is read from. For this to happen, I saved the ***time_print.js*** file in a directory named `www` in the same directory as our shinyApp.R file. The code in the .js file is shown next:

```
function js_print_time(){

var today1 = new Date();
var hr = today1.getHours();
var mn = today1.getMinutes();
var ss = today1.getSeconds();

if (hr.toString().length <2 ){hr = '0' + hr;} 
if (mn.toString().length <2 ){mn = '0' + mn;}
if (ss.toString().length <2 ){ss = '0' + ss;}

var pstamp = hr + ':' + mn + ':' + ss;  

document.getElementById("time_stamp").textContent = "";       //clear current div object contents.

document.getElementById("time_stamp").textContent += pstamp;  // Append pstamp to current value of div object, "". I thank Jesus!

}


setInterval(one_time_print,5000);
```

What this does is print the output of the javascript `js_print_time()`  function to shiny's web page (on the "time_stamp" div) every 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds), regardless of whether heavy tasks are running in the shinyApp's server.R.